# Read values from greyed out listbox?

Tags: windows

There are some settings in a program that are listed in a listbox, but because of some poor programming are greyed out and unable to be resized, and I need to know the full values contained in the list items.  I know of the Spy++ tool which can show information about buttons and other objects in Windows, but it doesn't tell me the data in the listbox.  What I'm looking for is a tool which can tell me the contents of the listbox.  Anyone know of such a tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use [SysExporter](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html) which can export data from just about any Windows element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AltMove](http://www.deskex.com/Altmove/index.asp) to force resize the box.